# Issue with returning multiple pieces of data from a function

Tags: python, string, loops, replace, split

I am trying to create a function that checks every line of the code and chops off everything at and after the pound sign on each line if there is present otherwise it will be unchanged. I am trying to return the same text but with each line chopped at the pound sign.

The problem is that when I print the text I see the result but when I return it nothing happens.

```
code_1='''
hello this is a test to remove anything after
 and to get #this letter out 
 def hello_world():        # this is a comment
    print("Hello world!") # this is another comment
print("I # like # pound sign # .")
'''

def remove_octothorpe_and_after(code):
    code_in_lines = code.splitlines()
    for i in code_in_lines:
        if '#' in i:
            index=i.index('#')
            aftertext=i[index:]
            i = i.replace(aftertext,"")
        new_code=("".join(i))
        return new_code
```

Comment: You can only return from a function **once**, so you probably don't want to do it inside a for loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you I move the return out of the loop but now I only see one line. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after updating `new_code`, if you print, it shows all the lines. But if you return it thats empty, you probably don't want to put that return statement inside a for loop as mentioned earlier.

In my approach, I stored all the updated lines in a list and joined them later in a string then returned the string.

Because `new_code` in each iteration is a different value.

```
def remove_octothorpe_and_after(code):
    code_in_lines = code.splitlines()
    upCode=[]
    for i in code_in_lines:
        new_code=""
        if '#' in i:
            ind=i.index('#')
            aftertext=i[ind:]
            i = i.replace(aftertext,"")
        new_code=("".join(i))
        updatedCode.append(new_code+"\n")
    s = ''.join(updatedCode) 
    return s

print(remove_octothorpe_and_after(code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Return doesn't work like that. Instead, use a list:

```
def foo():
    bar = []
    for x: 
        bar.append(y)
    return bar

print(foo())
```

Or convert to a generator:

```
def baz():
    for x:
        yield y

foobar = baz()

for result in foobar:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You return right after the first iteration, and you see an empty result because the first line is an empty string because it starts with:

`'''
hello this is a test to remove anything after`

If you would start it like this you would see only the first line.

`'''hello this is a test to remove anything after`

If you would move the return 1 indentation to the left you would only see the last line in the return as you will then overwrite `new_code=("".join(i))` in every iteration.

What you could do is create a list in the function to store the temporary results and when the loop is done return `"".join(tmp)`

If you want to return only the first part before `#` you could split and return the first item which is index 0 and append a newline to keep the separate lines.

```
code_1='''
hello this is a test to remove anything after
 and to get #this letter out 
 def hello_world():        # this is a comment
    print("Hello world!") # this is another comment
print("I # like # pound sign # .")
'''

def remove_octothorpe_and_after(code):
    code_in_lines = code.splitlines()
    tmp = []
    for i in code_in_lines:
        tmp.append(i.split("#")[0] + "\n")
    return "".join(tmp)

print(remove_octothorpe_and_after(code_1))
```

Result

```
hello this is a test to remove anything after
 and to get 
 def hello_world():        
    print("Hello world!") 
print("I
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ckFuK0)